# Extra luggage charges for a flight with Qatar Airways and JetBlue between India and the US

Tags: usa, luggage, qatar-airways, jetblue

I have flight from Ahmedabad, India to Raleigh, NC, USA. The flight detail is as follows:

- Ahmedabad to Doha - Qatar Airways | QR 535
- Doha to New York - Qatar Airways | QR 701
- New York to Raleigh - JetBlue Airways | B6 1185

Will I be charged for extra luggage by both airlines, i.e. Qatar and JetBlue?
What are the charges for additional weight (between 23-32 Kg) in comparison to a separate 23 Kg bag?

Comment: Is the trip on one ticket, or do you have separate tickets for each leg?

Comment: The answer depends on whether you have just one ticket or separate tickets. It also depends on whether after you check in your bag, are you required to collect it and *re-check in* again?

Comment: For the overweight charges regarding Qatar Airlines see [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38282/overweight-baggage-policy-in-qatar-airways).

Answer (score 5):

In your case, the Qatar Airways rule will apply; because they are the [most significant carrier](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/baggage-most-significant-carrier.page) on your journey.

You will have to recheck your bags though, as this is standard practice at the port of arrival in the US.

For your flight, its $50 per bag, and the maximum one bag can weight is 32KG. You will only pay this extra if you are flying on Economy as Business and First passengers already have a 32KG limit.

Irrespective of travel class, you can only check in two bags for free.

Comment: Are you sure of your statement `Irrespective of the airline, the charge for extra weight is always less than the charge for an extra bag.`. I found myself paying 23Euros per kg with Easyjet once. An extra luggage would have cost me *much* less.

Comment: I should have specified - non-LCC because with them its open season on fees.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Since the journey involves travel within/to/from the United States the "Most Significant Carrier" rule does not apply; instead US federal law requires that the same baggage allowance must apply equally throughout the entire itinerary. https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.87 The baggage fee and the permitted baggage allowance (for the entire journey) must be clearly displayed in the email confirmation: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.85

Comment: From the same link you quoted: _"In the case of code-share flights that form part of an itinerary whose ultimate ticketed origin or destination is a U.S. point, **U.S. and foreign carriers must apply the baggage allowances and fees of the marketing carrier throughout the itinerary to the extent that they differ from those of any operating carrier.**"_ - in this case the ticket is on Qatar Airways.