# Overweight baggage policy in Qatar Airways?

Tags: luggage, regulations, qatar-airways

I am travelling from USA to India with Qatar Airways, can I take two 32 KG as my check in baggage? instead of additional (3rd) baggage?

This would be with one carry on (hand luggage) and one laptop bag?

Comment: What "class" are you flying? Also, I am assuming your question is about checking in extra luggage without having to pay extra fees. If so I would advise you to modify it as to include as many details as possible. ;)

Comment: Economy Class.   I read we can carry 23KG (2 pc) with the maximum of 32 kg in one baggage. My question can I take 32kg ( 2PC) and pay the overweight cost instead of 3rd luggage.

Answer (score 6):

Qatar Airways has a [page on their website](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/baggage.page) with a handy table that explains all this:

> All other flights to and from Argentina, Canada, and the U.S.
>
> - 2 pieces, each not to exceed 32kg (70lb) and a maximum dimension of
>     158cm (62in) (First and Business Class)
> - 2 pieces, each not to
>     exceed 23kg (50lb) and a maximum dimension of 158cm (62in) (Economy
>     Class)

So it appears you can only check in two bags on all classes of travel, the only difference being the weight of each individual bag.

To check in a third bag, you would have to pay the [excess baggage fees](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page). These vary based on your flight itinerary.

In your case, for flights originating to/from the US at the time of this answer the charges are $200 per additional item; and $50 if your item exceeds the baggage allowance for your class of travel.

If you buy excess allowance offline (like at the counter or the airline office) an additional surcharge is added.

If you were traveling Economy your total charges would be:

- $50 x 2 = $100 (for each overweight bag)
- $200 (for an extra bag)
- $300 Total

If you were traveling on First or Business, you would only pay $200 for the extra bag as your weight limit is already 32KG.

I don't know of any airline that allows you to substitute a checked-in bag for a hand carry.

Comment: thank you so much. This clears I can take 2 (32 KG) bag without taking additional baggese which will save me 100$.

Comment: +1 For a good answer. I would add that the $50 per luggage is unique to flights `Flights to/from Argentina, Brazil, Canada and the USA`, like you did for the luggage allowance. This is to avoid the reader inadvertently thinking that this applies to flights to/from all destinations, which is not the case.