# Extra bag with Qatar Airways - Can i pay for an extra bag?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I am flying with Qatar Airways, Manchester to Melbourne, via Doha in March of this year. However I would like to check in an additional bag. However the website does not display a cost per bag, but simply per kilo. Why, when other airlines only charge £65 per extra bag (British Airways) do an airline such as Qatar not offer a similar service, but charge per Kilo. I am flying in 3 months so I have no idea how many kilos exactly I would need and to just pay for an additional bag seems so much more simple. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38282/overweight-baggage-policy-in-qatar-airways/38301#38301

Answer (score 1):

### Luggage Allowance on Qatar Airlines

The luggage allowance on Qatar Airlines operated flights is summarised in the table below (taken from the [Qatar Airlines Baggage webpage](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/baggage.page)):

[image: Qatar baggage]

Note that, quoting from the same page:

> A single piece of checked baggage must not weigh more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down such that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).

### Extra Luggage on Qatar Airlines

Indeed **you can purchase an extra bag wen flying with Qatar Airways, only if you are flying to/from the Americas** (Argentina, Brazil, Canada and the USA). Quoting from [their page on the matter](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page):

> - Excess baggage is charged per kilo except to / from the Americas, where it is charged per piece.

Excess baggage on flights to/from the remaining countries are charged by kilogram. Moreover, excess baggage for these countries can be sold in 5kg bundles. Quoting from the same page:

> - Purchase units are offered in increments of single pieces or bundles of 5kg (11lb) each.

This would somewhat allow you to buy an extra 5kg luggage.

The price per kilogram is dependent on departure and destination countries. It would seem that from Europe to Australia, the price per kilogram of excess luggage is 55USD if bought online and 70USD if bought in person (either ticket counter or check-in). Here is a screenshot from the [afore-mentioned Qatar Airwayspage](http://www.qatarairways.com/qa/en/excess-baggage-rates.page):

[image: Qatar extra bag.]

Comment: According to the chart, a 20 kg extra bag to Australia from EU would cost $1,100 USD.. that is more than 10 times of what it would cost in any other airlines...

Comment: But you get 30 kg for free even in cheapest economy, when most other airlines only offer 20 kg.

Answer (score 0):

I did fly with Qatar airways to Singapore, Doha, New York, and I'm telling you to not bring an extra baggage (they are very strict). Your suitcase for check in should not exceed 20 kilo, and the handbag should not exceed more that 10 kilo (30 overall). See their term and conditions for the business class or first class as they have additional benefits for them.  The best option is to update your ticket to Business class or First class; if you still want to bring extra baggage either as an additional handbag or suitcase.